# How to put multiple values into one http header entry

Tags: asp.net-core

Example in C# client

```
var c = new HttpClient();
c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-MyHeader", "123,abc"); // What delimiter? , ; & are not working.
```

In the Server

```
var Vals = Request.Headers["X-MyHeader"];
```

Since the `Headers` returns a `StringValues` object, may I know what delimiter shall I use at the client side, so that the string can be automatically parsed as '123' and 'abc' separately?

Answer (score 2):

### Let the `HttpHeaders` collection handle the separators.

The `Add()` method can be called multiple times with a single value or with a list of values.

The `HttpHeaders` collection doesn't behave the same as a `Dictionary<string, string>`. One key can contain multiple values. They are send separated by comma's. See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders.add?view=net-7.0

The list can be added in one call with the `Add(String, IEnumerable<String>)` overload, if you have the strings in a enumerable collection of some sort.

Comment: As you can see, I have already put comma in the value `123,abc`, but the server failed to recognize it is a separate values. Of course I can split that string myself, but I would like to do it the correct way.

Comment: @sk The Add() method probably escapes the ',' in the string value to let the server side reconstruct it as one string and not as multiple. It would be quite buggy if the Add() method would allow a comma embedded in the string mean anything special. A common example: Add("valname", val.ToString()) where val is a double. In cultures where commas are used as decimal separator this would go horribly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> may I know what delimiter shall I use at the client side, so that the
> string can be automatically parsed as '123' and 'abc' separately?

You were sending request headers in the right way,you could try some tricks in serverside read the header as an array.

For example,in controller,you could try with the default modelbinder and `[FromHeader]` Attribute,set     `[FromHeader(Name="X-MyHeader")] string[] headervalarr`  as an  argument  of your action method

the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#sources-1) related

[image]